# Event handling issue with label and input inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, event-bubbling

Issue with event handling with labels can any body explain the exact behavior for this reason

```
  <ul onclick="console.log('parent')" style="padding:15px; background-color:grey;" >
<li>
  <label style="padding:10px; background-color:white;">Checkbox with input has the click handler 
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="console.log('checked box is clicked')"/>
  </label>
</li>
```

Output: ***When click on label***

"parent"

"checked box is clicked"

"parent"

```
 <ul onclick="console.log('parent')" style="padding:15px; background-color:grey;" >
<li>
  <label onclick="console.log('checked box is clicked')" style="padding:10px; background-color:white;">Checkbox label has the click handler
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </label>
</li>
```

Output: ***When click on Label***

"checked box is clicked"

"parent"

"checked box is clicked"

"parent"

[jsbin link for ref](http://jsbin.com/qepaqufoco/edit?html,js,console,output)

*I want to know why? parent's event handler is getting triggered first when label is clicked.*

Comment: What do you want to happen exactly ?

Comment: I want to know why? parent event handler is getting triggered first when label is clicked.

Comment: @adeneo This is related to given question not duplicate

Comment: When you put an input inside a label, clicking the label will focus the input triggering the click on the input, and as events bubble, both events trigger on the label, so the answer is the same as in the duplicate.

Comment: @adeneo actually the issue I mentioned parent <ul> click handler is getting triggered before the child <input> click handler. when input is wrapped over the <label>